How can we improve image reconstruction from fMRI brain activity using Algonauts data?
I need help with the Argonauts Image Reconstruction task using brain fMRI data.I have images of places and objects paired with corresponding fMRI scans. I'm using autoencoders to obtain latent codes for the images and a brain recorder for brain activity vectors. I've tried adding more layers and using cosine similarity as a loss function in the brain decoder to improve reconstruction, but haven't succeeded. What steps can I take to enhance the reconstruction?
Currently, my architecture uses 256 latent dimensions and cosine similarity for the recorder.
Autoencoder Code:
class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_input_channels: int, base_channel_size: int, latent_dim: int, act_fn: object = nn.GELU):
        super().__init__()
        c_hid = base_channel_size # 32
        self.net = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(num_input_channels, c_hid, kernel_size=3, padding=1, stride=2),  # 32x32 => 16x16
            act_fn(),
            nn.Conv2d(c_hid, c_hid, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            act_fn(),
            nn.Conv2d(c_hid, 2 * c_hid, kernel_size=3, padding=1, stride=2),  # 16x16 => 8x8
            act_fn(),
            nn.Conv2d(2 * c_hid, 2 * c_hid, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            act_fn(),
            nn.Conv2d(2 * c_hid, 2 * c_hid, kernel_size=3, padding=1, stride=2),  # 8x8 => 4x4
            act_fn(),
            nn.Flatten(),  # Image grid to single feature vector
            nn.Linear(2 * 16 * c_hid, latent_dim), #64
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.net(x)


class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_input_channels: int, base_channel_size: int, latent_dim: int, act_fn: object = nn.GELU):
        super().__init__()
        c_hid = base_channel_size
        self.linear = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(latent_dim, 2 * 16 * c_hid), act_fn()) #64
        self.net = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(
                2 * c_hid, 2 * c_hid, kernel_size=3, output_padding=1, padding=1, stride=2
            ),  # 4x4 => 8x8
            act_fn(),
            nn.Conv2d(2 * c_hid, 2 * c_hid, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            act_fn(),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(2 * c_hid, c_hid, kernel_size=3, output_padding=1, padding=1, stride=2),  # 8x8 => 16x16
            act_fn(),
            nn.Conv2d(c_hid, c_hid, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            act_fn(),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(
                c_hid, num_input_channels, kernel_size=3, output_padding=1, padding=1, stride=2
            ),  # 16x16 => 32x32 # 1024
            # nn.Tanh(),  # If you want to bound the output
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.linear(x)
        x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], -1, 4, 4)
        x = self.net(x)
        return x


class Autoencoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(
        self,
        base_channel_size: int,
        latent_dim: int,
        encoder_class: object = Encoder,
        decoder_class: object = Decoder,
        num_input_channels: int = 3,
        width: int = 32,
        height: int = 32,
    ):
        super().__init__()
        self.encoder = encoder_class(num_input_channels, base_channel_size, latent_dim)
        self.decoder = decoder_class(num_input_channels, base_channel_size, latent_dim)

    def forward(self, x):
        z = self.encoder(x) # Latent code
        x_hat = self.decoder(z) # Reconstruction
        return x_hat


Decorder
class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_input_channels: int, base_channel_size: int, latent_dim: int, act_fn: object = nn.GELU):
        super().__init__()
        c_hid = base_channel_size
        self.linear = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(latent_dim, 2 * 16 * c_hid), act_fn()) #64
        self.net = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(
                2 * c_hid, 2 * c_hid, kernel_size=3, output_padding=1, padding=1, stride=2
            ),  # 4x4 => 8x8
            act_fn(),
            nn.Conv2d(2 * c_hid, 2 * c_hid, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            act_fn(),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(2 * c_hid, c_hid, kernel_size=3, output_padding=1, padding=1, stride=2),  # 8x8 => 16x16
            act_fn(),
            nn.Conv2d(c_hid, c_hid, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            act_fn(),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(
                c_hid, num_input_channels, kernel_size=3, output_padding=1, padding=1, stride=2
            ),  # 16x16 => 32x32 # 1024
            # nn.Tanh(),  # If you want to bound the output
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.linear(x)
        x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], -1, 4, 4)
        x = self.net(x)
        return x


